# Issue with jest "Unexpected token 'export'"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, recharts

I have a problem with the following error when I run my jest tests
In a project we are using a package which underwater uses the D3 library.

When I run a test which uses that component I get the following message:

```
node_modules\d3-shape\src\index.js:1

{export {defauls as arc} from "./arc.js"}


SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I have tried updating my jest.config and changing the transformIgnorePatterns but not having any success

Answer (score 1):

same issue as above :3 This issue occurs when I upgrade recharts from 2.1.9 to latest (2.1.14), rollback to 2.1.9 will resolve it but it makes conflict due to I upgraded to React 18

Answer (score 0):

You can try it :D

```
"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!d3-shape)/\"",
```

I tried and it successful